# Rewriterule for two index.php files - pls help me

Tags: mod-rewrite

I want to use RewriteRule for two index.php files which contain explode function.

*www.domain.com/1/index.php and
www.domain.com/2/index.php*

**I want to build multilevel directories for both ie:**
www.domain.com/1/europe/germany
www.domain.com/2/africa/maroco

**I have first condition**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^?]*)$ /1/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**but i don't know where/how put second condition for directory /2/**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your RewriteRule pattern is too broad, you need to use the leading `/1/` or `/2/` :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^?]*)$ /$1/index.php?path=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This rule use the leading number to dispatch the query to the right script.